# running wp8 application on tablet

Tags: windows-phone-8, deployment

I created a windows phone app (works on WP 8 & 8.1) and published the app to the windows phone store for beta testing.
I tried to download and install the app on my windows tablet ie a Dell windows 8 tablet http://www.flipkart.com/dell-venue-8-pro-tablet/p/itmdutftjdkcec3x?pid=TABDUTFZW4XKAYPS
And it says the application is not supported on the device.
So can is any way to run the application ( mobile application ) on the tablet .
Can i directly deploy xap file on tablet ? If so how?
Or is any other way to make it work on the tablet as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The Surface tablets runs Windows 8 and therefore can install Windows store apps. It doesn't run Windows Phone and can't run Windows phone apps.

There are two different development environments with two different SDK's. If you want to work your app on windows 8 as Windows store app you can use Universal app. [Link1](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/Building-universal-Windows-apps), [Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx)

Comment: I fully agree with kumar

Comment: I did a mistake in choosing the product to test the mobile app. I think the tablet Dell Venue 8 will run on windows mobile OS and once i got product in hand then only realized its wrong product. Now arguing with flipkart.com for a refund / exchange . Lets hope some positives will happen soon

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot deploy windows phone apps on winRT. But windows PC apps do run on windows surface. You have a separate SDK for developing windows surface apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared (Universal) app to run it in both environments .